# simple networking/routing question

Tags: networking

I need server A to be able to reach server C (a mail server). server B can already reach server C and server A can reach server B. Is there a few simple steps I can take to add a static route to server A to solve this?

Comment: Need more info.  Are these machines on the same network?  What do you mean by 'reach eachother' and what OS is each machine running?

Answer (score 2):

No, at least in IP space.

If they aren't on the same subnet (xxx.yyy.zzz.1 and xxx.yyy.zzz.2) the two computers will require a router to connect them. If they are on the same subnet then a switch is all that is required.

Given the simplicity of you question means we're guessing blind, I'd first recommend that you check to see if A and C both have a "default gateway" that matches an IP of a local router for each of their subnets. And I'd check for firewalling (both software and hardware) at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

- A is 10.1.0.1/24
- C is 10.2.0.1/24
- B is both 10.1.0.2/24 and 10.2.0.2/24
- B has an OS on it that permits routing, or forwarding:

on A:

```
route add -host 10.2.0.1 10.1.0.2
```

on B:

- make sure forwarding is enabled; this is done in different ways by different OSs

on C:

```
route add -host 10.1.0.1 10.2.0.2
```

Now A should be able to interact with C, and vice versa.

(Warning: route syntax above is from Solaris, because that's what I have historically spent most of my time with; linux and windows routing is done slightly differently.  Also, making all these changes permanent across reboots is left as an exercise to the reader.)

Comment: Syntax for Windows is: route add x.x.x.x mask 255.255.255.255 y.y.y.y (where x = destination, y = ip of 2nd network card)

Comment: Will Windows really act as a router without extra networking software being installed? Is there a Role that allows this?

Comment: @Mark -- usually  you have to turn it on for most OSs (although by default Solaris will enable routing if it boots with two interfaces with separate subnets defined).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, more information is needed.

If Server A is Windows you can try:

`route ADD ServerCIPAddress MASK NetMaskOfABSubNet  ServerBIPAddress`

however it's likely that the three servers are on different subnets, which means this won't work...

In that case you will need to do something about the router / switch configuration.

Comment: ok, thank you. They are on different subnets. I'll see if I can find someone to help w/the router.