# simple networking/routing question

Tags: networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [simple networking/routing question](https://serverfault.com/questions/56238/simple-networking-routing-question)

I need server A to be able to reach server C (a mail server). server B can already reach server C and server A can reach server B.  Is there a few simple steps I can take to add a static route to server A to solve this?

Comment: What operating system(s) are A and B running?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to both servers A and B, you can do this on server A:

sudo route add server.C.ip.address server.B.ip.address

and on server B you need to turn on packet forwarding.  If it's a unixy/BSD system you might do that via:

sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1

If you don't have root access to both servers, there's no way to do what you want.